# How do I print the linked list returned by a function

Tags: c

```
struct Node {
    int element;
    struct Set *next;
};

struct Set {
    struct Set *head;
    struct Set *tail;
}; 

struct Set SET_union(struct Set s, struct Set t) {
        struct Set u = SET_new();
        struct Node *node = s.head;

        for (node = s.head; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
            SET_add(&u, node->element);
        }
        for (node = t.head; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
            if (!SET_contains(&u, node->element))
                SET_add(&u, node->element);
        }
        return u;
    }

    ...

    printf("%i\n", SET_union(set, set1));
```

When I run this code, SET union returns the memory address to the returning set instead of the elements within the newly created set. How do I get the function to return the elements within the set?

Comment: `SET_union` does not return anything as it has a empty body. I guess you meant to show the prototype without body? If so, `SET_union` returns a `struct Set` which you cannot print with the format specifier `%i`.

Comment: Yeah I meant to show it that way. I kinda knew already that was the problem. How do I print it then?

Comment: You need to print the struct members separately. Can you show the definition of `struct Set`?.

Comment: what about now?

Comment: You need to manually walk through the list and print each element.

Comment: @dbush He does not exactly have to walk it manually.  First of all, because manually means "with the hands", while walking is done with the legs.  Secondly, because he needs to actually write some code that will do it for him. So, he will not have to visit each node either with his hands or with his legs.  The code will do it.  C-:=

Comment: How do I go through the list? How do I loop through u in main?

Comment: @vale46 Did you write any of the above code or was it given to you?  Because most of the logic is right there.

Comment: I wrote it. Its a hw assignment.

Comment: @vale46 So save a copy of the new set and loop through it just like you do in the function above, printing on each iteration.